# The phrase "as much as I used to....."

Tags: comparative-constructions

Hello guys so I have a problem with an expression. So here are two sentences:

> I do not run as much as I  **used to**.
>
> I do not run as much as I **used to do**.

I don't know which one of the two phrase is the correct one. I would be glad if you could help me out.

Answer (score 1):

> I do not run as much as I used to.
>
> I do not run as much as I used to do.

Both examples are natural.

They are not phrases; they have both the subject and predicate and are hence clauses, independent clauses in fact as they express a complete idea.